# stripe-payments system not returning "name" field in webhooks

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to get line_items in the 2020/08 stripe API version over webhooks, but it is not returned in the webhook. My code is:

```
$session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
    'customer' => $user,
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  //'metadata' => ['item_id' => '6735'],
  'line_items' => [[
    'name' => 'cows',//$name,
    'description' => $description,
    'images' => ['https://www.mathtutortime.com/account/add_time/selected/tutoring.jpg'],
    'amount' => 0050.00,
    'currency' => 'usd',
    'quantity' => 1,
    ],
  ],
  'mode' => 'payment',

  'success_url' =>'https://www.mathtutortime.com/account/add_time/selected/success2?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}&bought='.urlencode($description).'',
  'cancel_url' => 'https://www.mathtutortime.com/account/add_time/selected/failure',
]);
```

, and what is returned in the checkout session event is:

```
{
  "id": "evt_1IuOvpBaP49eHvWwXFoFZzsB",
  "object": "event",
  "api_version": "2020-08-27",
  "created": 1621805637,
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "id": "cs_test_a1U80BcqqjXeudvxrYDCUr34w5YZBUCKRN8qCdCMx7wGWnGMhtrP7I3xFk",
      "object": "checkout.session",
      "allow_promotion_codes": null,
      "amount_subtotal": 50,
      "amount_total": 50,
      "billing_address_collection": null,
      "cancel_url": "https://www.mathtutortime.com/account/add_time/selected/failure",
      "client_reference_id": null,
      "currency": "usd",
      "customer": "rickster26ter4",
      "customer_details": {
        "email": "rick.giovanini1@gmail.com",
        "tax_exempt": "none",
        "tax_ids": [
        ]
      },
      "customer_email": null,
      "livemode": false,
      "locale": null,
      "metadata": {
      },
      "mode": "payment",
      "payment_intent": "pi_1IuOvFBaP49eHvWw9jkdH1nb",
      "payment_method_options": {
      },
      "payment_method_types": [
        "card"
      ],
      "payment_status": "paid",
      "setup_intent": null,
      "shipping": null,
      "shipping_address_collection": null,
      "submit_type": null,
      "subscription": null,
      "success_url": "https://www.mathtutortime.com/account/add_time/selected/success2?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}&bought=1+Hour+of+Tutoring+%2B+Premium+Dashboard+Features",
      "total_details": {
        "amount_discount": 0,
        "amount_shipping": 0,
        "amount_tax": 0
      }
    }
  },
  "livemode": false,
  "pending_webhooks": 1,
  "request": {
    "id": null,
    "idempotency_key": null
  },
  "type": "checkout.session.completed"
}
```

There is no line_items, or even "name". Also, I get the error returned from my webhook:

```
                <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property 'custom' of non-object in <b>/var/www/html/account/add_time/selected/success/webhook.php</b> on line <b>30</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property 'name' of non-object in <b>/var/www/html/account/add_time/selected/success/webhook.php</b> on line <b>30</b><br />
```

Thanks for any help. Stripe has not been much of any help so far...

Answer (score 0):

`line_items` are [not returned by default](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-line_items).  You need to re-retrieve the Checkout Session and [expand `line_items`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects).

Comment: can you explain more what you mean by that? I thought I was expanding line items by doing this: "line_items' => [[
    'name' => 'cows',//$name, ..."

Comment: You're creating them by doing that; you need to add an argument to expand them too: https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects